# Interacting with Wordpress website API from mobile app

Tags: c#, php, json, wordpress, api

I am developing an app that is presented with a login screen containing the usual username and password text inputs.

When pressing the Login button the code is supposed to make a HTTP Web Request to the Wordpress website as an attempt to log in.

I have had a look at the WP plugins called `JSON API` and `JSON API USER`
but the documentation is very limited.

How would I go about to properly log in to the Wordpress website as well as retrieving user information from databases?

**NOTE:**
I'm developing in Xamarin but any code examples from any language is fine, as I could easily port the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to the Wordpress website's system and interact with it, you need to indeed make a few API calls.

Using the plugins `JSON API` and `JSON API USER` is the easiest way to do so.

1. Install `JSON API` and `JSON API USER` plugins from the website control panel
2. Make a Web Requests, one after another, to get nonce and get authorization cookie using the the following calls:

Nonce: `http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=generate_auth_cookie&insecure=cool`

and

Auth Cookie: `http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=USERNAME_HERE&password=PASSWORD_HERE&insecure=cool`

**NOTE:**

At the end of the requests you can see the parameter `insecure=cool`.

This is used for unsecured communication.